# random behavior and infinite looping in arm cortex m4

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I am trying to write code to take some values as duty cycles from uart and write them to pwm outputs to drive 6 motors.

```
PWM_Init();
UART_Init();
char x;
uint32_t y;
uint32_t sum[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint32_t i,j,k;
while(1)
{
    for(k = 0 ; k < 7 ; k++)
    {
        sum[k] = 0;
    }
    //////////////// 
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
        {
            x = UART_InChar();
            y = (x -'0') * pow(10,2-(j));
            sum[i] += y;
        }
    }
    //////////////////
    PWMPulseWidthSet(PWM1_BASE, PWM_OUT_0,5000 - sum[0]);
    PWMPulseWidthSet(PWM1_BASE, PWM_OUT_1,5000 - sum[1]);
    PWMPulseWidthSet(PWM1_BASE, PWM_OUT_2,5000 - sum[2]);
    PWMPulseWidthSet(PWM1_BASE, PWM_OUT_5,5000 - sum[3]);
    PWMPulseWidthSet(PWM1_BASE, PWM_OUT_6,5000 - sum[4]);
    PWMPulseWidthSet(PWM1_BASE, PWM_OUT_7,5000 - sum[5]);
}
```

while debugging the 2nd for loop exceeds 7 and continues to run sometimes with large values of i and maybe infinite. I don't know the reason for this and how to solve this problem.

Comment: How many iterations does `for(k = 0 ; k < 7 ; k++)` do, and how many elements of `sum` are there, exactly?

Comment: no specified number each time it iterates with randon number, almost all times it counts more than 7 so 6 sum elements one for each motor are determined then the code stops waiting for new input characters @Notlikethat

Comment: `for(k = 0 ; k < 7 ; k++)  { sum[k] = 0;` writes to `sum[6]` which is outside `uint32_t sum[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};` --> undefined behavior.  Also `sum[i] += y;`.

Comment: That's right. Thank you @chux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` loops are [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of you are addressing your array out of bounds. `sum` array is `6` element wide. This means that indexes start from `0` to `5`.

You should write

```
for(k = 0 ; k < sizeof(sum)/sizeof(sum[0]) ; k++)
{
    sum[k] = 0;
}
```

I guess that the second loop, due to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), is resetting/changing the value of `i` that is the first declared/allocated variable after `sum` array declaration.